# Math - big number from couple of numbers export-able

Tags: math

Let's say I have some numbers, like

```
5,10,7,8,9,6,2,4,8,5,3,9,78,5,6
```

I need to send this to another computer, but as the least number of possible bytes. I know what there is a way to do that, I just forgot what it's called and how it works, but generally doing some math with those numbers, getting a big number that, from this number, I'll be able to export the data and get this numbers from this number. Thanks in advance.

EDIT
OK so I need to send this text in UDP but I need it as less bits as possible. I'm sending some options, like firstcolor-secondcolor, let's say I have 15 colors. Every color is just number, from 1 to 199, but maybe there is a better way to send this data? thanks.

Comment: Is the word you are looking for compression?

Comment: Hmmm yea haha lol :D, but still, I don't know what would the best way to do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one can say which compression scheme is the best for you. We don't have any information about the numbers. But as a first try, you could just write them into a file and use `gzip` compression on it. Or `bzip2`, or `7zip`.

And only if all these don't help, you should think about doing the compression yourself.

You also didn't tell us your operating systems (source computer, destination computer) and from where you get the data.

[Update, based on the edit in the question:] So basically you want to send some numbers in the range of 1 to 199. This is pretty close to what a single `byte` can hold.

If it is ok that you use 8 bits per number (meaning you waste 0.4 bits per number), this is trivial but highly depends on the programming language. Here is how it might look like in Java syntax:

```
ByteBuffer buf = new ByteBuffer();
buf.add(1);
buf.add(199);
buf.add(78);
buf.add(7);

udpSocket.send(buf.toArray());
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I know on the server side that 1,199,78 and 7 are different numbers..?

Comment: On the server side you have to interpret the packet as a `ByteBuffer` as well. I thought this was obvious, but as your questions are pretty unclear it is difficult for me to answer them. By the way, you should put *all* important information into the question. (programming language, your knowledge, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Get a compression library (like `zlib`, for example) and feed your numbers in (as an array of integers, for example).  This is *compressing* your data.  That same library should allow you to reverse the process and *decompress* the data at the other end to get your values back out.

If you want to improve your algorithmic knowledge and your requirements are simple and non-critical I'd recommend having a go at writing your own compression/decompression code.  If not, grab some code off the shelf - there are *loads* of good libraries around.

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm using C++ as the server and obj-c for the client. Can you give me an example of using this zlib? Also is this the best solution for me, do you think? Thanks.

Comment: zlib is a C library so that should be workable at both client and server ends.  The official site is http://www.zlib.net/ but I'm afraid I don't have any specific examples to offer (bet Google will throw plenty up though).  As for whether it's the _best_ solution that depends on many factors, with performance being a key one.  zlib is pretty fast and you can compress in-memory and avoid the IO cost of writing to/reading from a file.  Compression/decompression doesn't come for free time-wise, of course.